# Remainder is less than divisor

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm reading a book and it says the equation
$$ a \bmod n = a - n \left\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\right\rfloor$$
follows that $$ 0 \leq a \bmod n \lt n. $$

I understand that the remainder is less than divisor, but I can't understand how the author got it from the first equation. Could someone, please, explain it to me?

Comment: Suggestion:  look at definition of greatest integer function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\lfloor x\rfloor \le x<\lfloor x\rfloor +1$, we have
$$ 0\le \frac an-\left\lfloor \frac an\right\rfloor <1$$
and after multiplication with $n$ the claim.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for very easy explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Since we have that
$$\frac{a}n-1\lt\left\lfloor\frac{a}n\right\rfloor\le\frac{a}n$$
Then we can bound the RHS by
$$a-n\left(\frac{a}n\right)\le a-n\left\lfloor\frac{a}n\right\rfloor\lt a-n\left(\frac{a}n-1\right)$$
$$0\le a-n\left\lfloor\frac{a}n\right\rfloor\lt n$$

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks much!